# Why Must Prime Ring Elements Not be Units?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $p, a, b \in R$.  We say that $p$ is a prime element of $R$ if (i) $p$ is not a unit and (ii) $p \mid ab \implies p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

My question is why is it necessary to force $p$ to not be a unit?  This automatically, for example, means that no element of a field can be prime.

Comment: $p \neq 0$ is also required.

Comment: Do you think of $1$ as a prime number?

Answer (score 4):

It is just a definition. It makes it possible to state uniqueness of prime factorizations without any case distinctions, just to name one example. Also $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not a prime number. And yes, fields have no prime elements.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that we want to exclude trivial prime factorisations. In the integers, if the unit 1 is prime, then 3.2=3.2.1 are two distinct prime factorisations of 6.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a unit in a ring $R$ with identity, then for any $a,b\in R$, we always have $p|ab$, $p|a$ and $p|b$. The definition excludes this uninteresting case.